# Is there anyway to simplify if/elif blocks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a pretty new (and bad) at python, and I was just wondering if there is anyone who can help me simplify a if/elif block. It's a super basic code, which basically asks what someone wants in a password and then randomises a pswd for them. But there are options if the user wants uppercase and numbers.

```
if upper == True and numbers == True:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
elif upper == True and numbers == False:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters
elif upper == False and numbers == True:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
elif upper == False and numbers == False:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase
```

sorry for the noob question guys

thanks a bunch guys, this has really helped :)

just reviewing for my igcse's and Im trying to relearn proper procedure. my teacher isn't that strong in python

Answer (score 5):

Every `== True` is useless. After that, notice that `numbers` have something in common, and extract it out.

```
if upper:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters
else:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase

if numbers:
    lettersAndDigits += string.digits
```

You could squeeze it a bit further, but Pythonistas will probably hate it on principle:

```
lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters if upper else string.ascii_lowercase
if numbers:
    lettersAndDigits += string.digits
```

Comment: thanks man, this is very fluid and super condensed. I will need to change the types of numbers and upper, but it won't be that hard

Answer (score 3):

You could start your character list in an empty array, and add characters to is as you go. Something like:

```
lettersAndDigits = []
if upper:
    lettersAndDigits += string.ascii_uppercase

if lower:
    lettersAndDigits += string.ascii_lowercase

if numbers:
    lettersAndDigits += string.digits
```

This will also allow you to use any combination, whereas you only account for four combinations in your code.

Comment: Why 2 if-blocks with the same condition though? Just a typo?

Comment: Because I'm a muppet. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 1):

So one thing you can do straight away is get rid of the `== True` and `== False` part, as the variables themselves are booleans which you are just comparing to see if they are booleans. As well, you don't *need* to do elif becuase only one of these wll return true, so you can just have a bunch of if statements which does look a bit nicer.

```
if upper and numbers:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

if upper and not numbers:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters

if not upper and numbers:
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

if not upper and not numbers
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase
```

Other than that, in this example there's not a whole lot more you *can* do. Programming unfortunately sometimes is pretty ugly, and python doesn't have switch so you're out of luck with that.

If anyone has any other thoughts I hadn't considered feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small list with the 4 combinations, then use `upper` and `numbers` to select the correct string right away. No `if`s required.

```py
import string

lettersAndDigits = [[string.ascii_lowercase,string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits],
    [string.ascii_letters,string.ascii_letters + string.digits]]

upper = False
numbers = True
print (lettersAndDigits[upper][numbers])
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
upper = True
numbers = False
print (lettersAndDigits[upper][numbers])
# abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can simplify that much more. Nevertheless, you can express it differently nested if blocks that maybe is easier to read:

```
if upper == True:
    if numbers == True:
        lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    else:
        lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters
else:
    if numbers == True:
        lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    else:
        lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an abusive one-liner (don't use this!):

```
allowed_chars = [string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_letters][upper] + string.digits * numbers
```

Using conversion of `bool` to `0, 1` to index a `list` and `str` by `int` multiplication, followed by `str` addition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what types are your `upper` and `numbers` variables, but unless their values are `None`, `0`, `[]` (empty list), `{}` (empty dict), `''` (empty string) they all are True. So you can simplify it to:

```
if variable:        # if variable == True:
    pass
```

or

```
if not variable:    # if variable == False: 
    pass
```

So simplified:

```
if upper:
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_letters
else:
    letters_and_digits = string.ascii_lowercase
if numbers:
    letters_and_digits += string.digits
```

Also, look [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#type-variable-names) to read about proper way of naming your variables.